# Cakephp not allowing Post external data

Tags: cakephp, http-post, payment-gateway

I'm trying to integrate a CakePHP website with Mercadopago (payment gateway), and when Mercadopago sends a POST containing the payment data, CakePHP doesn't show the POST, and I'm completely sure that the data was sent.

I tried to set the security level to low and it doesn't works.

Is there any Cake "behaviour" that cleans the POST data?

Comment: Might be the [`SecurityComponent`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) blocking the posted data

Comment: Have you check that it's not a [cross domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issue? How are you calling Mercadopago, is it js or php or other? How are you checking the response? Could you share the code of that?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the $_POST variable.
Instead, you should use:

```
$this->request->data
```

Cake will recieve al post data there.

Try:

```
debug($this->request->data);
```